# binding source declaration in xaml: object name of class name?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is my code:

```
<ListView x:Name="monitorEventList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=MonitorEventCollection}">
```

Actually MonitorEventCollection is a class name defined by me, I guess the Binding Source should be an object? am I right? So I guess a default constructor is called during the code initialization to create an object from a class. I set a breakpoint in the constructor, but it's not called.

So I'm confused. How does xaml run when it sees a class name in binding source?

Answer (score 0):

Your object needs to have a property of that class. The object is created in code, in the XAML, you bind to the property name. So:

```
public MonitorEventCollection Foo { ... }
```

is bound to with

```
<ListView x:Name="monitorEventList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foo}">
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{Binding Path=Foo}` or just `{Binding Foo}`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you are mistaken about how this works. You *can* use a class like this, but not in this way. To find out about how to use a class in this way, please take a look at the [ObjectDataProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx) page on MSDN.

To use your XAML example, you would need to change it slightly:

```
<ListView x:Name="monitorEventList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PropertyName}">
```

...where `PropertyName` is a public property from an *instance* of a class that is data bound as the `DataContext` of this (or a parent) control.